# How to change only the time of a datetime field for a specific time between two dates

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table in SQL Server that stores many entries with `datetime` columns. I want to change time from 08:30:00:000 to 08:00:00:000 between the dates 2017-06-01 and 2017-06-30.

Example data is below:

```
ID      FIELD1   FIELD2    START_DATETIME             END_DATETIME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
18936     48       2       2017-06-01 19:00:00:000    2017-06-02 08:30:00:000
18937      5       2       2017-06-01 19:00:00:000    2017-06-02 08:30:00:000
18938      4       2       2017-06-01 19:00:00:000    2017-06-02 08:30:00:000
18939     46       2       2017-06-01 19:00:00:000    2017-06-02 08:30:00:000
18940     40       2       2017-06-02 08:30:00:000    2017-06-02 19:00:00:000
18941     16       2       2017-06-02 08:30:00:000    2017-06-02 19:00:00:000
18942     21       2       2017-06-02 08:30:00:000    2017-06-02 19:00:00:000
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified my answer since you want to update the data in the table.

```
--Change START_DATETIME
UPDATE yourTable --replace with your table name 
SET START_DATETIME =  (DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, START_DATETIME))
WHERE START_DATETIME > '2017-06-01'
      AND
      END_DATETIME < '2017-07-01'
      AND
      CAST(START_DATETIME AS TIME) = '08:30:00'
GO

--Change END_DATETIME
UPDATE yourTable --replace with your table name
SET END_DATETIME =  (DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, END_DATETIME))
WHERE START_DATETIME > '2017-06-01'
      AND
      END_DATETIME < '2017-07-01'
      AND
      CAST(END_DATETIME AS TIME) = '08:30:00'
GO
```

Comment: @CaferElgin I changed my answer. This worked for me on my test table.

Comment: @cafer-elgin, between the dates 2017-06-01 and 2017-06-30 mentioned in the question. So inclusive of dates 2017-06-01 and 2017-06-30, the condition would be >= and<=

Comment: @JayaPrakash Those 2 fields are in a datetime format. This means that any entry that has ANY time value on 6/1/2017 will be included. The logic is saying values between 6/1/2017 midnight and 7/1/2017 midnight.

Comment: Yes, it is. For start_datetime, it is okay, as 00:00:00 will be used if time not passed. But for End_datetime we need results till 23:59:59, but here condition will be checked against 2017:07:01 00:00:00 instead of 2017:07:01 23:59:59

Comment: @JayaPrakash Correct. The end range is 2017-6-30, so `2017-6-30 23:59:59` will still be included if we say less than `2017-07-01 00:00:00`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `update`. For `start_datetime` it would be:

```
update t
    set start_datetime = dateadd(minute, -30, start_datetime)             
    where start_datetime >= '2017-06-01' and
          start_datetime < '2017-07-01' and
          cast(start_datetime as time) = '08:00:00';
```

You can do something similar with `end_datetime`. Or both at once:

```
update t
    set start_datetime = (case when cast(start_datetime as time) = '08:00:00'
                               then dateadd(minute, -30, start_datetime)
                               else start_datetime
                          end),
         end_datetime = (case when cast(end_datetime as time) = '08:00:00'
                              then dateadd(minute, -30, end_datetime)
                              else end_datetime
                          end)
    where start_datetime >= '2017-06-01' and
          start_datetime < '2017-07-01' and
          (cast(start_datetime as time) = '08:00:00' or
           cast(end_datetime as time) = '08:00:00'
          );
```

This assumes that the date range is determined by `start_datetime`.

Comment: So, will this search for time 08:30 or 08:00?

Comment: In update statement, cast(start_datetime as time)='08:30:00'